# How can I set "grails.gorm.default.mapping" in SpringBoot with GORM, and no Grails

Tags: grails-orm

I'm using GORM with SpringBoot, not in Grails.
How can I set "grails.gorm.default.mapping" and "grails.gorm.default.constraints" since SpringBoot only support properties in application.yml.

Thx!

Comment: I'm concept proving GORM for a Spring Boot application, but there are just too many obstacles so far. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: this worked:https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/07/spring-sweets-using-groovy-configuration-propertysource/